# HTML anchor, but not exact at anchor point

Tags: html, anchor

When I want to refer to some part of a webpage with the "http://example.com/#foo"-method, I do:

```
<h1 id="foo">Foo Title</h1>
```

But the idea is I need to go above or beyond that anchor by some distance in pixels, for example:

```
"http://example.com/#foo-100px" 
   or
"http://example.com/#foo+100px"
```

I've been thinking about this overnight, haven't got any idea how to do that. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Is JS an acceptable option?

Comment: I rather not but if I have to so be it.

Comment: I posted an answer using jQuery. If you want a vanilla js solution, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a separate anchor instead of your heading as the link target, you can use negative margins to accomplish this without affecting the rest of your layout.

```
#myAnchor {
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
}

<p>My paragraph.</p>
<a name="myAnchor" id="myAnchor"></a>
<h1 id="myHeading">My heading</h1>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dfL361wa/)

Comment: Fiddle updated to better demonstrate the effect and use a 100px offset.

Comment: I like the idea. It seems the "margin-bottom" is not needed. I am slow, need some time to chew it through. :) Thanks!

Comment: The bottom margin is needed to preserve the layout positions of other elements.

Comment: So the margin-top would have negative and margin-bottom would have positive px with the same magnitude. This scheme would let you go above the anchor. How do you make it to go beyond the anchor?

Comment: You're not trying to go beyond the anchor. You set the anchor some distance above the heading you're trying to show. See the demo. The heading is 100px down the page, just like you requested.

Answer (score 0):

There is no avoiding using a scripting language for this, at least, not that I know of.  Here's a simple jQuery solution: http://code-tricks.com/offset-scroll-to-anchor-tag-with-jquery/

```
$(function(){
 $("[href^='#']").not("[href~='#']").click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var obj = $(this),
  getHref = obj.attr("href").split("#")[1],
  offsetSize = 145;
  $(window).scrollTop($("[name*='"+getHref+"']").offset().top - offsetSize);
 });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vg0x45gy/

Set the `offsetSize` variable to how many pixels you want it offset by.  Use a positive value for above the anchor point and a negative value for below it.